# wavesurfer.js destroy() causes Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot close a context that is being closed or has already been closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, domexception, wavesurfer.js

I'm using [wavesurfer](https://wavesurfer-js.org/) to show song waveforms on my web page. I'm using the following code -

```
function setupSongwaves(songJson) {
    var songwaveid = '#song-waveform' + songJson.songid;

    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: songwaveid,
        height : 80,
        barWidth : 4,
        cursorWidth : 2,
        waveColor: 'blue',
        cursorColor: 'white',
        progressColor: 'red'
    });

    wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
        console.log('ready');
        // wavesurfer.play();

        setTimeout(function () {
            destroyCurrentSongwaves()
        },2000);
    });

    $(document).on("destroy-songwaves", function () {
        wavesurfer.destroy();
    });

    // Hard coding song for now
    wavesurfer.load('../assets/song1.mp3');
}

function destroyCurrentSongwaves() {
    $.event.trigger({
        type: "destroy-songwaves"
    });
}
```

As soon as `wavesurfer.destroy()` is called I get the following error message in my console -

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Cannot close a context that is
>   being closed or has already been closed.

Things appear to be working fine, but I get this error every time and I can't figure out what seems to be the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try to upgrade Wavesurfer to the current latest version 1.3.7, it should resolve the problem.